# Error in values passed byref calling a dll in python

Tags: python, dll, shared-libraries, ctypes, byref

I have to different dlls exporting this functions (one function each dll):

dll1:

```
DECLDIR void getFrameworkVersion(int* pMajor, int* pMinor, int* pBugfix);
```

dll2:

```
void __stdcall getFrameworkVersion(int* pMajor, int* pMinor, int* pBugfix);
```

Im importing both dlls in python with no errors, and calling them with no errors either. However I'm getting wrong values

```
dll1 = cdll.LoadLibrary('dll1')
dll2 = oledll.LoadLibrary('dll2')

pMajor = pMinor = pbugFix = c_int()

dll1.getASTFrameworkVersion.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)]
#test.eval.restype = ctypes.c_double
dll1.getASTFrameworkVersion(byref(pMajor), byref(pMinor), byref(pbugFix))
astVersion = "AST Framework version: " + str(pMinor.value) + "."  + str(pbugFix.value) + "."  + str(pMajor.value)

dll2.getFrameworkVersion.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)]
dll2.getFrameworkVersion(byref(pMajor), byref(pMinor), byref(pbugFix))
asfVersion = "ASF Framework version: " + str(pMinor.value) + "."  + str(pbugFix.value) + "."  + str(pMajor.value)
```

I'm getting this output:

```
    AST Framework version: 0.0.0
    ASF Framework version: 14.14.14
```

Comment: The "14.14.14" is caused by the print, where you say three times `str(pMajor.value)`.

Comment: Yes... you are right. What a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing it. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pMajor = pMinor = bugFix = c_int()` is wrong: all three Python names are the same `c_int` instance, so will contain the same value!  What you're doing is equivalent to the following code in C:

```
int x;
getFrameworkVersion(&x, &x, &x);
```

So the fact that you get `0.0.0` is probably because the real result would end in `.0`, which overwrites the previous two values.